# Specify environment on start of component

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We are having docker based build and deployment and below mentioned is our *docker-compose.yml* file.

```
web:
  image: stage.example.com/logcomponent:latest
  ports:
    - "80"
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: DEV
```

We are running it using `docker-compose up -d`. Is there a way to specify `NODE_ENV` value from command like for e.g. `docker-compose up -d PROD` or `docker-compose up -d DEV`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compose manual says you can declare an environment variable without it's contents (and it leaks through from the host) :

[https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#environment](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#environment%20environment)

Your declaration could be written like this:

```
web:
  image: stage.xxx.com/logcomponent:latest
  ports:
    - "80"
  environment:
    NODE_ENV:
```

Then, when you bring up the composition from the command line :

```
NODE_ENV=DEV docker-compose up -d.
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked! you could accept my answer if you think it is correct :-)

Comment: no, i don't think so.  you can 'upvote' an answer (which is what you did I think).  There is also an 'accept' (a check mark) meaning that the answer was correct.   It's no big deal :-)